# Check if a parameter is passed to MyBatis or not inside MyBatis mapper

Tags: mybatis

I am passing a map to MyBatis with some parameters. Now these parameters are based on the incoming JSON request... So the numbers of parameters are variable.

So sometimes it can happen that some parameter is not coming in that case MyBatis throws `BindingException` in the null check itself ... What is the suggested way to handle this kind of scenario.

Comment: If the `Map` is the sole parameter, `<if test="_parameter['id'] != null">and id = #{id}</if>` or `<if test="_parameter.containsKey('id')">and id = #{id}</if>` may be what you are looking for. If not, please add the details.

Comment: @ave will try this out and confirm with you.